# Need to quickly connect/disconnect multiple Bluetooth headsets in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, toggle, switch-statement

Is there a quick way to do this? I have 2 regulat phone BT headsets, and a stereo BT headset for music. I need to be able to quickly disconnect and reconnect any of those without having to power them off (and without having to gi to  settings/wireless/bluetooth settings). Is there any app out there that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this ? It is recommended for the HS's to initiate and connect to the phone and not the other way round, this is recommended for better user experience and interoperability.

Comment: I have an 2011 Audi, and the phone is connected using both the mono phone BT profile and A2DP stereo for music streaming. But there's BT interference when both are connected at the same time, and the only way to make it work right is to disconnect a2dp when not in use. There is no way to do it from the car itself -- once it's connected, it stays connected

Comment: Seems like a poorly implemented bluetooth in the Phone. Ideally when the call comes in (mono BT profile aka HS/HF) the A2DP streaming should pause and resume after the call. The bluetooth bandwidth (depending on implementation and version of Bluetooth in the phone / car ) might not be enough to have both HS/HF and A2DP streaming go on simultaneously

Comment: That may be true, but has nothing to do with my original question -- I need to be able to quickly connect and disconnect the BT headsets, without having to go into the BT settings menu

Comment: I have a very similar issue, but as biker. I need to have my helmet bt disconnected when I take it off.for a short period without turning it off. So a one button connect / disconnect would be perfect